# Why do we need to convert the double into a string, before we can convert it into a BigDecimal?

Tags: java, math

The source for [round](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/util/MathUtils.html#round%28double,%20int,%20int%29) in apache commons looks like this:

```
public static double round(double x, int scale, int roundingMethod) {
    try {
        return (new java.math.BigDecimal(Double.toString(x)).setScale(scale, roundingMethod)).doubleValue();
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        if (Double.isInfinite(x)) {
            return x;
        } else {
            return Double.NaN;
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering, when creating the `BigDecimal` why did they chose to convert the double to a string (using the `Double.toString`) instead of simply using the double itself?

In other words, what's wrong with this? :

```
public static double round(double x, int scale, int roundingMethod) {
    try {
        return (new java.math.BigDecimal(x).setScale(scale, roundingMethod)).doubleValue();
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        if (Double.isInfinite(x)) {
            return x;
        } else {
            return Double.NaN;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the result of `BigDecimal(double)` constructor is unpredictable as mentioned in javadoc.

> One might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
>   BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with
>   a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>   0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
>
> The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable:
>   writing new BigDecimal("0.1") creates a BigDecimal which is exactly
>   equal to 0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, it is generally
>   recommended that the String constructor be used in preference to this
>   one.

Test Case:

```
System.out.println(java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1).toString());
System.out.println(new java.math.BigDecimal(0.1).toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for the constructor `BigDecimal(String val)` :

> Note: For values other than float and double NaN and ±Infinity, this
>   constructor is compatible with the values returned by
>   Float.toString(float) and Double.toString(double). This is generally
>   the preferred way to convert a float or double into a BigDecimal, as
>   it doesn't suffer from the unpredictability of the BigDecimal(double)
>   constructor.

Comment: And if you really want to see the difference, remember BigDecimal source is available.

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/math/BigDecimal.java.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert to String.
Use the static method [`BigDecimal.valueOf(double val)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29):

To use in your code:

```
...
return (BigDecimal.valueOf(x).setScale(scale, roundingMethod)).doubleValue();
....
```

Comment: The docs wrote that `BigDecimal.valueOf(x)` is equivalent to doing `new java.math.BigDecimal(Double.toString(x))`, so basically I was wondering what's the difference between `new java.math.BigDecimal(Double.toString(x))` and `new java.math.BigDecimal(x)` ?

Comment: If that's how it's implemented, so be it. That may change in future JDKs. Focus on the API - the implementation shouldn't worry you (unless of course it truly affects your design decisions, which would probably mean your design is flawed in some way)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the key is in this statement:

> BigDecimal(double val) 
>             Translates a double into a BigDecimal which is the exact decimal representation of the double's binary floating-point value.

versus

> BigDecimal(String val) 
>             Translates the string representation of a BigDecimal into a BigDecimal.

By going to String first, you just see the double as a BigDecimal, but if construct directly from a double, you're working with the bit-level representation, and I'm willing to bet you'd get a subtly different answer.  Remember that floating-point values are represented using a sections of the 64-bits for the whole part, and a section for the fraction part, and a section to represent an exponent (in base 2) -- it's all very esoteric stuff, differs from machine to machine, and I think the only formal definition is found in the accursed [Necronomicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necronomicon).

Update: What [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073912/why-do-we-need-to-convert-the-double-into-a-string-before-we-can-convert-it-int/8073972#8073972) said.

Answer (score 1):

However, I found one question:

```
System.out.println(java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625).toString());
```

It will print **0.1**.

I think the key is **java.lang.Double.toString(double d)**. When we input **0.1**(In Java, the exact value is **0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625**), the function will drop the tail and we get **0.1**. However. if we input **0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625**, it always drop the tail and we also get **0.1** which is against our expectation.

So we must be aware of our requirement to choose **java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(double val)** or **java.math.BigDecimal.BigDecimal(double val)**.

Comment: yea if we wanted that to work we had to `new java.math.BigDecimal("0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625")`