# Is it sufficient to convert a double to a BigDecimal just before addition to retain original precision?

Tags: java, double, precision, bigdecimal

We are solving a numeric precision related bug. Our system collects some numbers and spits their sum.
The issue is that the **system does not retain the numeric precision,** e.g. 300.7 + 400.9 = 701.599..., while expected result would be 701.6. The precision is supposed to adapt to the input values so **we cannot just round results to fixed precision.**

The problem is obvious, we use double for the values and addition accumulates the error from the binary representation of the decimal value.

The path of the data is following:

1. XML file, type xsd:decimal
2. Parse into a java primitive double. Its 15 decimal places should be enough, we expect values no longer than 10 digits total, 5 fraction digits.
3. Store into [DB MySql 5.5, type double](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html)
4. Load via Hibernate into a JPA entity, i.e. still primitive double
5. Sum bunch of these values
6. Print the sum into another XML file

Now, I assume the optimal solution would be converting everything to a decimal format. Unsurprisingly, there is a pressure to go with the cheapest solution. It turns out that converting doubles to [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) just before adding a couple of numbers works in case B in following example:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Arithmetic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 0.3;
        double b = -0.2;
        // A
        System.out.println(a + b);//0.09999999999999998
        // B
        System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(a).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(b)));//0.1
        // C
        System.out.println(new BigDecimal(a).add(new BigDecimal(b)));//0.099999999999999977795539507496869191527366638183593750
    }
}
```

More about this:
[Why do we need to convert the double into a string, before we can convert it into a BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073912/why-do-we-need-to-convert-the-double-into-a-string-before-we-can-convert-it-int)
[Unpredictability of the BigDecimal(double) constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218515/unpredictability-of-the-bigdecimaldouble-constructor)

I am worried that such a workaround would be a ticking bomb.
First, I am not so sure that this arithmetic is bullet proof for all cases.
Second, there is still some risk that someone in the future might implement some changes and change B to C, because this pitfall is far from obvious and even a unit test may fail to reveal the bug.

I would be willing to live with the second point but the question is: Would this workaround provide correct results? Could there be a case where somehow

```
Double.valueOf("12345.12345").toString().equals("12345.12345")
```

is false? Given that Double.toString, according to javadoc, prints just the digits needed to uniquely represent underlying double value, so when parsed again, it gives the same double value? Isn't that sufficient for this use case where I only need to add the numbers and print the sum with this magical [Double.toString(Double d)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)) method? To be clear, I do prefer what I consider the *clean solution*, using BigDecimal everywhere, but I am kind of short of arguments to sell it, by which I mean ideally an example where conversion to BigDecimal before addition fails to do the job described above.

Comment: "2. Parse into a java primitive double" By the time you've done this, you've lost the precision. Parse it straight away to a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: If you need guaranteed precision, `double` should not be used in any part of your processing.

Comment: You lose precision the moment you parse your data into a `double`. There is no way for a `double` to contain the value `0.2` precisely. It's simply not representable in binary format. But it is printed "correctly" because string conversion takes this into account and rounds it. This is why direct conversion of the `double` is unpredictable.

Comment: What they said: the moment you touch `double`, it's broken.  BigDecimals only, and really only then if you convert directly from Strings: `BigDecimal.valueOf("0.3")`, not `BigDecimal.valueOf(0.3)`.

Comment: Yes, a floating point format does not internally represent a decimal value precisely. Anyway double is precise enough to hold a 15digit number so that when e.g. 10-digit value, parsed from a String to double, is printed to String again with the special rounding algorithm in Double.toString, I should yield the same value from which I parsed the double in the first place, right? Then this String is used to construct the BigDecimal which in turn is used for the math. I am missing some other pitfall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't avoid parsing into primitive `double` or store as double, you should convert to `BigDecimal` as early as possible.

`double` can't exactly represent decimal fractions. The value in `double x = 7.3;` will never be exactly 7.3, but something very very close to it, with a difference visible from the 16th digit or so on to the right (giving 50 decimal places or so). Don't be mislead by the fact that printing might give exactly "7.3", as printing already does some kind of rounding and doesn't show the number exactly.

If you do lots of computations with `double` numbers, the tiny differences will eventually sum up until they exceed your tolerance. So using doubles in computations where decimal fractions are needed, is indeed a ticking bomb.

> [...] we expect values no longer than 10 digits total, 5 fraction digits.

I read that assertion to mean that all numbers you deal with, are to be exact multiples of `0.00001`, without any further digits. You can convert doubles to such BigDecimals with

```
new BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.round(doubleVal * 100000), 5)
```

This will give you an exact representation of a number with 5 decimal fraction digits, the 5-fraction-digits one that's closest to the input `doubleVal`. This way you correct for the tiny differences between the `doubleVal` and the decimal number that you originally meant.

If you'd simply use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double val)`, you'd go through the string representation of the double you're using, which can't guarantee that it's what you want. It depends on a rounding process inside the Double class which tries to represent the double-approximation of 7.3 (being maybe 7.30000000000000123456789123456789125) with the most plausible number of decimal digits. It happens to result in "7.3" (and, kudos to the developers, quite often matches the "expected" string) and not "7.300000000000001" or "7.3000000000000012" which both seem equally plausible to me.

That's why I recommend not to rely on that rounding, but to do the rounding yourself by decimal shifting 5 places, then rounding to the nearest long, and constructing a BigDecimal scaled back by 5 decimal places. This guarantees that you get an exact value with (at most) 5 fractional decimal places.

Then do your computations with the BigDecimals (using the appropriate MathContext for rounding, if necessary).

When you finally have to store the number as a double, use `BigDecimal.doubleValue()`. The resulting double will be close enough to the decimal that the above-mentioned conversion will surely give you the same BigDecimal that you had before (unless you have really huge numbers like 10 digits before the decimal point - the you're lost with `double` anyway).

P.S. Be sure to use `BigDecimal` only if **decimal** fractions are relevant to you - there were times when the British Shilling currency consisted of twelve Pence. Representing fractional Pounds as `BigDecimal` would give a disaster much worse than using doubles.

Comment: Very well explained. I'd +2 if I could. <g>

Comment: Thanks, very kind of you :-)

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration! Why is it necessary to shift the decimal point before the conversion? According to javadoc and a test with a couple of arbitrary numbers, [BigDecimal.valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double)), should provide the correct value, though I cannot really test all the numbers :-)
BTW I assume you suggest using the factory method and the `new` keyword is there by a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Database you are using. If you are using SQL Server you can use data type as numeric(12, 8) where 12 represent numeric value and 8 represents precision. similarly, for my SQL DECIMAL(5,2) you can use.

You won't lose any precision value if you use the above-mentioned datatype.

Java Hibernate Class :

You can define 
private double latitude;

Database:

[image: Database Design]

Comment: You are ignoring the fact that the number was parsed into `double` in the first place, thus lost precision already. The type to use in the database is less important - all databases have a way of representing exact decimal numbers.

Comment: @RealSkeptic when converted to a String you can reliably get the decimal you started with depending on how many digits you need.